# discord.py v2 commands not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

music bot that use to work in discord.py v 1.7.3 now doesn't play audio so i tried updating it to discord.py v2 but cannot figure out why my commands are now not found.

BOT SETUP

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

from music_cog import music_cog

# Creating a bot instance
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?", intents=intents)

#this will get called when bot is online
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready!")

@bot.command(name="ping", aliases=["latency", "P"], help="Displays bot latency in an embed")
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=(
            f'Latency  =  {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms'),
        colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
        await bot.start('TOKEN')

asyncio.run(main())
```

MUSIC SETUP

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
        #Bots state
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []

        #lib options 
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'False'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

     #searching the item on youtube
    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try: 
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception: 
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # infinite loop checking 
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
            
            
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            
            
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    
    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name = "resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)


    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if (i > 4): break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"  
        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in queue")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
    async def dc(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

all aplications are on path and being accesed(ffmpeg, ytdlp) no erros when running the code other than "Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found"

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the asyncio changes in discord.py v2.0, the loading and unloading of extensions and cogs is now asynchronous ([read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous)).
This way you will need to load the `music_cog` in an async context as shown below:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from music_cog import music_cog
import asyncio

# Creating a bot instance
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?", intents=intents)

#this will get called when bot is online
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready!")

@bot.command(name="ping", aliases=["latency", "P"], help="Displays bot latency in an embed")
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=(
            f'Latency  =  {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms'),
        colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
        await bot.start('TOKEN')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This has fixed the runtime error warning with my cog but my commands are still not found

Comment: Please update the post with the new code

Comment: updated code. also went back and tested commands in discord.py 1.7.3(they worked) so i must be doing something wrong with the updated api

Comment: Are the commands outside of the Cog working? Can you use `?ping`?

Comment: yes the ping command and bot event is working.