# Discord.py bot couldn't detect commands after applied cog

Tags: python, discord.py

here is both the main.py and Vige.py files

**here's the main.py file**

```
#COGS
initial_extensions = []

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])

print(initial_extensions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(extension)

client.run(token)
```

**and here's the vige.py cog file:**

```
class Vige(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def welcome(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Thanks for the warm welcome! I'm Vige, your personalized chat bot, ready to serve!")
        await ctx.send("https://giphy.com/gifs/starwars-star-wars-episode-3-xTiIzJSKB4l7xTouE8")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Vige(client))
```

I used to have all of the commands in one main.py file, but recently tried to use cogs from a tutorial.

and the errors have all been the same, resulting in terminal output like this:
[cogs.Vige]
2024-01-08 21:16:01 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "welcome" is not found

Comment: You need to load the extension in an asynchronous context. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967628/discord-py-v2-commands-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exaple:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def my_command(self, ctx:commands.Context):
        await ctx.send('Hello from MyCog!')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def channel(self, ctx:commands.Context):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(1147497954538696744)
        await channel.send(channel)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

You need to load your cog asynchronously. And you need `await client.load_extensions()`

*Note: I'm working with bot so you'll need to change bot to client.*